# Spring Session JDBC - error using @Autowired Objects

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-session

In order to save the sessions in a Database, I have implemented the Spring Session JDBC using this example [here](https://dzone.com/articles/spring-jdbc-session). I am having problems using the @Autowired with session scope: 
I have Java Class `Dump` as follow:

```
public class Dump 
{
    private String someName;

    public Dump(){}

    public Dump(String someName) {
        this.someName = someName;
    }

    public String getSomeName() {
        return someName;
    }

    public void setSomeName(String someName) {
        this.someName = someName;
    }
}
```

And then I am registering this bean in a `SESSION_SCOPE` as following:

```
@Configuration
public class DumpConfig{

    @Bean
    @Scope(value = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_SESSION, proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
    public Dump getDump() {
        return new Dump();
    }

}
```

In a controller I am wiring it and trying to use:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class HomeController {

    @Autowired
    private Dump dump;

    @GetMapping("/dump")
    @ResponseBody
    public String demo() {
        return dump.getSomeName();
    }
}
```

When I try to run I get this error:

```
Failed to convert from type [java.lang.Object] to type [byte[]] for value 'Dump@35b2136e' nested exception is org.springframework.core.serializer.support.SerializationFailedException
```

Comment: Your `Dump` must be `Serializable` else it won't be stored in the session. Not so much an issue with `@Autowired` but an effect of storing something in the session.

Comment: @M.Deinum the problem is that I am using a Library that I can not Serialize its own Java classes.

Answer (score -1):

Please refer to the video in the below mentioned link(around 1:14) the speaker says that this issue is resolved in spring 3.0 by providing a proxy of non-serializable beans, which obtains an instance from the current application context (on deserialization).

**https://www.infoq.com/presentations/Whats-New-in-Spring-3.0**